# Move semantics, Curiously recurring template pattern and memory leak

Tags: c++, indexing, memory-leaks, move-semantics, crtp

I've imlemented a varation of the curiously recurring template pattern:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template<typename T>
struct Indexed
    {
private:
    static int s_maxIndex;
    static std::map<int, T> s_map;

    int m_index;
    void SetNewIndex () { m_index = ++s_maxIndex; }

protected:
    Indexed (T&& t)
        {
        SetNewIndex ();
        s_map.insert (std::pair<int, T> (m_index, std::move (t)));
        }

    T&                                      GetMappedRef () { return s_map[m_index]; }
    static T&                               GetMappedRef (int index) { return s_map[index]; }

public:
    int                                     GetIndex () const { return m_index; }
    static std::map<int, Indexed> const&    GetAll () { return s_map; }
    static void                             Clear () { s_map.clear (); }
    };

template<typename T>
int Indexed<T>::s_maxIndex = 0;

template<typename T>
std::map<int, T> Indexed<T>::s_map;

struct MyObj
    {
    int m_myData;
    MyObj () = default;
    MyObj (int data)
        :m_myData (data)
        {
        }
    };

struct MyObjHandler : public Indexed<MyObj>
    {
    MyObjHandler (int value)
    :Indexed (MyObj (value))
        {
        }

    MyObj& GetObjRef ()
        {
        return GetMappedRef ();
        }

    static MyObj& GetObjRef (int index)
        {
        return GetMappedRef (index);
        }
    };

void test ()
    {
    MyObjHandler objH1 (4), objH2 (5);
    std::cout << objH1.GetIndex () << ", " << objH2.GetIndex () << std::endl;
    std::cout << objH1.GetObjRef().m_myData << ", " << objH2.GetObjRef().m_myData << std::endl;
    }

int _tmain (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
    test ();

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks ();

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Here are two examples of where using "MyObjHandler" instead of "MyObj" would make sense:

1. To represent a graph where each node is associated to an instance of "MyObj". We store at each graph node an index and use the global mapping to get the corresponding instance of "MyObj".
2. Creating an instance of "MyObj" in a scope makes that instance fall out of scope at the end of the scope:

   void CreateObj ()
   {

   MyObj obj;

   //operations on obj;

   }
   //obj falls out of scope

But I want to keep that instance for later use. Therefore I need to leverage the power of move semantics.

It seems to work, but it gives memory leaks:

> Detected memory leaks!
>
> Dumping objects ->
>
> {216} normal block at 0x0063D1A0, 24 bytes long.  Data: <  c H c   c
>
> > A8 D0 63 00 48 D1 63 00 A8 D0 63 00 00 00 CD CD
>
> {215} normal block at 0x0063D148, 24 bytes long.  Data: <  c   c   c
>
> > A8 D0 63 00 A8 D0 63 00 A0 D1 63 00 01 00 CD CD
>
> {214} normal block at 0x0063D100, 8 bytes long.  Data: <@       > 40
>   A3 14 01 00 00 00 00
>
> {213} normal block at 0x0063D0A8, 24 bytes long.  Data:
>
> > 48 D1 63 00 48 D1 63 00 A0 D1 63 00 01 01 CD CD
>
> Object dump complete.

**Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is normal. You could try to comment the call to the `test` function, the memory leak is still there (smaller, but still there).

In my opinion, the _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks incorectly identify the static map as a memory leak - it was allocated at the begining of the program and it is still in use. This behavior is consistent with the one specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/d41t22sb.aspx) :

> When an unfreed block is encountered, _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks calls
>   _CrtMemDumpAllObjectsSince to dump information for all the objects allocated in the heap from the start of program execution.

If you comment out the static map, the memory leak is gone.